# Occational connection reset during TCP handshake when using Kestrel

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have ten Windows Servers,  some are Windows 2016, some other 2019.
Each of them run the same application to make up a cluster.  The application is basing on .NET Core v6.  It exposes ASP.NET Core WebAPI on Kestrel and released as self-hosted binaries.

The application runs well except in peak hours, there is a tiny channce (<0.1%) that client encoutners connection reset error on connection establishing in peak hours.  It happened to different clients and multiple servers. First I suspected server was overloaded,  so I doubled the number of servers from ten to twenty, it is better but the issue is still there.

Then I suspected that TCP backlog was running out, hence I tuned the servers' Windows registry to increase backlog size,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"TcpTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001E
"MaxUserPort"=dword:0000fffe
"StrictTimeWaitSeqCheck"=dword:00000001
"EnableDynamicBacklog"=dword:00000001
"MinimumDynamicBacklog"=dword:00000232
"MaximumDynamicBacklog"=dword:000003eb
"DynamicBacklogGrowthDelta"=dword:0000000a
"MaxFreeTcbs"=dword:00003E80
"MaxHashTableSize"=dword:00010000
```

and also set a big number of Backlog in Kestrel.

```
                builder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.AddServerHeader = false;
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = false;
                    options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
                    options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
                    options.ListenAnyIP(port);
                })
                .UseSockets((options) => options.Backlog = 1000);
```

**It does not help. The error still occurs there.
Then I switched it to use http.sys instead,  the issue disappeared.**

```
                builder.UseHttpSys((options) =>
                {
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = false;
                    options.Authentication.Schemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    options.MaxConnections = null;
                    options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add($"http://*:{port}");

                });
```

It seems something wrong in Kestrel, or I was using it in a wrong way somehow, and caused the issue.  Does anyone encounter connection reset error in Kestrel?